# Expand Json based on relation

Tags: javascript

I have following JSON data, If any one of the child name is matching with any of the parent name then i want to create new json set.

```
var PARENT_CHILD = {
  'Newton': ['Plato', 'Aristotle'],
  'Aristotle': ['Einstein'],
  'Plato': ['Tesla', 'Edison'],
  'Einstein': ['Hawking']
};
```

I want to convert it into like below:

```
 {
  "Newton": {
    "child": "Plato, Aristotle"
  },
  "Plato": {
    "parent": "Newton",
    "child": "Tesla, Edison"
  },
  "Aristotle": {
    "parent": "Newton",
    "child": "Einstein"
  },
  "Einstein": {
    "parent": "Aristotle",
    "child": "Hawking"
  },
  "Tesla": {
    "parent": "Plato"
  },
  "Edison": {
    "parent": "Plato"
  },
  "Hawking": {
    "parent": "Einstein"
  }
 }
```

Comment: Please include a proper [mre] of your current code directly inside the question, instead of just dumping it onto an external platform.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask: _“if it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - **but also copy the code into the question itself.** Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time.”_

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) on the entries in `PARENT_CHILD`, creating a new entry in the output for the parent (if it doesn't already exist) and adding the `child` array to it, and then creating a new entry (with `parent` property) for each of the children of that parent:

```js
var PARENT_CHILD = {
  'Newton': ['Plato', 'Aristotle'],
  'Aristotle': ['Einstein'],
  'Plato': ['Tesla', 'Edison'],
  'Einstein': ['Hawking']
};

var result = Object.entries(PARENT_CHILD).reduce((acc, [parent, child]) => {
  if (acc[parent]) {
    acc[parent].child = child.join(', ');
  } 
  else {
    acc[parent] = { child : child.join(', ') };
  }
  child.forEach(name => acc[name] = { parent });
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```